# how to unsubscribe to an observable that makes a switchMap

Tags: angular, rxjs

here is the following code which allows me to make an http request to a server to have a given status among several possible (pooling data).

```js
getIntervalStatus(sessionId: string): Observable<HttpResponse<string>> {
  return interval(1000).pipe(
    switchMap(value => {
      return this.getStatus(sessionId);
    }),
  );
}
```

How can I unsubscribe from the observable returned by `interval(1000)`?

When I unsubscribe with the subscription of `getIntervalStatus.subscribe()` it does not stop `interval (1000)` which continues to transmit. See example below

```js
this.getIntervalStatusSubscription = this.device.getIntervalStatus(this.printerVMService.getSessionId()).subscribe(
  status => {
    switch (this.status) {
      case 'opened':
        break;
      case 'payed':
        this.getIntervalStatusSubscription.unsubscribe();
        break;
      case 'closed':
        this.getIntervalStatusSubscription.unsubscribe();
        break;
      case 'used':
        this.getIntervalStatusSubscription.unsubscribe();
        break;
      default:
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [takeWhile](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takewhile) to keep the connection open until a certain condition is met?

```js
// this observable auto-unsubscribes when status not 'opened'
status$ = this.device.getIntervalStatus().pipe(
  takeWhile(status => status === 'opened')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In the file where you subscribe for this observable implement following:
1. Create variable from type BehaviorSubject for example

```
isDestroyed: BehaviorSubject<false>
```

2. Before subscribe to your observable use **takeUntil** operator from RxJS and pass inside your behavior subject like:

```
takeUntil(this.isDestroyed)
```

3. Then in **onDestroy** component lifecycle  emit value:

```
this.isDestroyed.next(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you're facing arises due to your `switch` statement.
You use `this.status` inside your `switch` statement instead of the status from your `getIntervalStatus`. Try:

```
this.getIntervalStatusSubscription = this.device.getIntervalStatus(this.printerVMService.getSessionId()).subscribe(
             status => {
              switch (status) {//use the status from the subscribe method
                case 'opened':
                  break;
                case 'payed':
                  this.getIntervalStatusSubscription.unsubscribe();
                  break;
                case 'closed':
                  this.getIntervalStatusSubscription.unsubscribe();
                  break;
                case 'used':
                  this.getIntervalStatusSubscription.unsubscribe();
                  break;
                default:
              }
            },
```

You can also simplify your subscribe method, you want to unsubscribe for every status, except for `'opened'`. So you could write:

```
this.getIntervalStatusSubscription = this.device.getIntervalStatus(this.printerVMService.getSessionId()).subscribe(
             status => {
              if(status !== 'opened'){
                this.getIntervalStatusSubscription.unsubscribe();
              }
             }
            },
```